# Make opening clickable filenames from Help mode in same window

Tags: help-mode, buttons

When I'm in `Help-mode` buffer generated from `describe-function` or similar command - after placing cursor on clickable filename text I wish to open this file in the same window (ideally I wish I could also kill this help buffer the same time). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `push-button` function wrapper:

```el
(defun eab/push-button-on-file-same-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((cwc (current-window-configuration))
        (hb (current-buffer))
        (file? (button-get (button-at (point)) 'help-args)))
    (funcall
     `(lambda ()
        (defun eab/push-button-on-file-same-window-internal ()
          (if (> (length ',file?) 1)
              (let ((cb (current-buffer)))
                (set-window-configuration ,cwc)
                (switch-to-buffer cb)
                (kill-buffer ,hb)))))))
  (call-interactively 'push-button)
  (run-with-timer 0.01 nil 'eab/push-button-on-file-same-window-internal))
```

It implements required behaviour.

Upd. Removed unnecessary `file-exist-p` checking. Now it works for `C source` files.

Comment: I tried to bind this function to enter like this `(define-key button-map (kbd "<RET>") 'eab/push-button-on-file-same-window)` and it still opens file in other window, but also showing message `Invalid read syntax: "?"`

Comment: Yes, I've just tested it in emacs 24.3.1 and it does not work. I use emacs 24.5.1 and it works there. I will think it over.

Comment: Well, my emacs is 25.1.50.1

Comment: just a quick note - I made it work just changing in `help-function-def` and `help-variable-def` function calls of `pop-to-buffer` to `switch-to-buffer`. Its looking not very good so I'll wait for other answers though.

Comment: I've fixed time: 0.01 instead of 0. Now it works on my emacs 25.1.50.2